# Is disconnecting an unauthorized websocket enough to secure an application?

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I've a small express app which relies on WS to deliver real-time data to logged in users.

For this purpose there is a login EJS page as well as dashboard, where socket.io does its magic.

Theoretically, a user shouldn't even be able to see the socket code located on the dashboard, but if for whatever reason a user is logged in but the session cookie is deleted -

**is setting up middleware to simply `.disconnect()` the socket enough to reasonably secure the app?**

Comment: I think this question is hugely subjective. What do you mean exactly by "secure"? I'd imagine that it's only as secure as what you implement. If you are doing your authentication on socket.io connection, then yes disconnect should suffice. If you're doing it on every single socket emission, then you probably don't even need to bother with that.

Comment: @MattFletcher Understandable re: nebulousness of the question. Your comment does answer it so feel free to leave it as an answer

Comment: Cheers. Well if I do leave an answer I'll try and do something a bit more fleshed out